# if statement problem?

Tags: c++, if-statement

My program is up and running but there is a problem with my if statements somewhere that is making "scalene" be the output in addition to the correct output (unless scalene is the correct output). take a look at the issue:

[image]

Can anyone spot the bug?

**triangleShape function**

```
# include "header.h"

triangleType triangleShape(float sideLength1, float sideLength2, float sideLength3)
{
    triangleType triangle;

    if (sideLength1 + sideLength2 < sideLength3)
        triangle = noTriangle;
    else if (sideLength1 + sideLength3 < sideLength2)
        triangle = noTriangle;
    else if (sideLength3 + sideLength2 < sideLength1)
        triangle = noTriangle;
    else if (sideLength1 == sideLength2 == sideLength3)
        triangle = equilateral;
    else if (sideLength1 == sideLength2)
        triangle = isoceles;
    else if (sideLength1 == sideLength3)
        triangle = isoceles;
    else if (sideLength2 == sideLength3)
        triangle = isoceles;
    else
        triangle = scalene;

    return triangle;
}
```

**output function**

```
# include "header.h"

void output (float sideLength1, float sideLength2, float sideLength3)
{
    if (triangleShape (sideLength1, sideLength2, sideLength3) == noTriangle)
        cout << "Side lenghts of " << sideLength1 << " " << sideLength2 << " and " << sideLength3 << " would not form a triangle." << endl;
    else if (triangleShape (sideLength1, sideLength2, sideLength3) == equilateral)
        cout << "A triangle with sides of lengths " << sideLength1 << " " << sideLength2 << " and " << sideLength3 << "would be " <<
        "an equilateral triangle."<< endl;
    else if (triangleShape (sideLength1, sideLength2, sideLength3) == isoceles)
        cout << "A triangle with sides of lengths " << sideLength1 << " " << sideLength2 << " and " << sideLength3 << "would be " <<
        "an isoceles triangle."<< endl;
    else (triangleShape (sideLength1, sideLength2, sideLength3) == scalene);
        cout << "A triangle with sides of lengths " << sideLength1 << " " << sideLength2 << " and " << sideLength3 << " would be " <<
        "a scalene triangle."<< endl;
}
```

Comment: On a related note, I suggest you the use a `switch`/`case` construct or a lookup table to avoid all these `if`, it would make the code more readable and avoid this kind of errors.

Comment: In addition to any other problems, the comparison `if (sideLength1 == sideLength2 == sideLength3)` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Matt: @Blastfurnace is right on that one - you need two separate checks, ie:  `if ((sideLength1==sideLength2) && (sideLength1==sideLength3))`

Comment: It's also worth thinking about the fact that if your input ends up being an actual scalene triangle you'll have made 4 calls to `triangleShape()` to figure this out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have an extra semi-colon on this line:

```
 else (triangleShape (sideLength1, sideLength2, sideLength3) == scalene);
```

Remove the semi-colon at the end, and add an `if` in the line (or remove the check completely).  It's causing the print following the "else" to always occur, as it becomes a separate statement.

You can do either of these:

```
 else if (triangleShape (sideLength1, sideLength2, sideLength3) == scalene)
    cout << "A triangle with sides of lengths " << sideLength1 << " " << sideLength2 << " and " << sideLength3 << " would be " <<
    "a scalene triangle."<< endl;
```

Or:

```
 else // There are no other options here...
    cout << "A triangle with sides of lengths " << sideLength1 << " " << sideLength2 << " and " << sideLength3 << " would be " <<
    "a scalene triangle."<< endl;
```

That being said, you might want to consider running your function one time and storing the results, then doing your checks against that result (or even using a [switch statement](http://www.intap.net/~drw/cpp/cpp04_02.htm)).

---

In addition, as pointed out by [Blastfurnace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/445976/blastfurnace), your comparison is incorrect.  You should use:

```
if ( (sideLength1 == sideLength2) && (sideLength1 == sideLength3))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
else (triangleShape (sideLength1, sideLength2, sideLength3) == scalene);
```

should be

```
else if (triangleShape (sideLength1, sideLength2, sideLength3) == scalene)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void output (float sideLength1, float sideLength2, float sideLength3)
{
    if (triangleShape (sideLength1, sideLength2, sideLength3) == noTriangle)
        cout << "Side lenghts of " << sideLength1 << " " << sideLength2 << " and " << sideLength3 << " would not form a triangle." << endl;
    else if (triangleShape (sideLength1, sideLength2, sideLength3) == equilateral)
        cout << "A triangle with sides of lengths " << sideLength1 << " " << sideLength2 << " and " << sideLength3 << "would be " <<
        "an equilateral triangle."<< endl;
    else if (triangleShape (sideLength1, sideLength2, sideLength3) == isoceles)
        cout << "A triangle with sides of lengths " << sideLength1 << " " << sideLength2 << " and " << sideLength3 << "would be " <<
        "an isoceles triangle."<< endl;
    else (triangleShape (sideLength1, sideLength2, sideLength3) == scalene);
        cout << "A triangle with sides of lengths " << sideLength1 << " " << sideLength2 << " and " << sideLength3 << " would be " <<
        "a scalene triangle."<< endl;
}
```

The last else should not have a semicolon at the end.

Comment: I think he probably intended an "if" directly after the else, and no semicolon before the last "cout"...